# how to disable firefox maximize button for popup window?

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

how to disable firefox maximize button for popup window?

Comment: I don't think this is a SuperUser question, folks. I think he's asking if there's an attribute you can use in `window.open` to do this.

Comment: I voted to close the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: ada chaluva maakan phoenix. tell correct solution or else moodikitu iru

Comment: And can you translate the above mentioned comment of yours to English.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open

try dialog=yes

Comment: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/openDialog

Answer (score 2):

Dear friend, unfortunately has no way to disable the minimize and maximize buttons in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, only in IE, this script is to force the size of the browser screen, so if someone wants to expand will not. Abs

use javascript....

```
var width = 1028;
var height = 800;
window.moveTo((screen.availWidth/2)-(width/2),(screen.availHeight/2)-(height/2)) 
window.resizeTo(width,height);

window.onresize = function() {window.resizeTo(width,height); }
```

\o/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute

resizable

to be false to prevent the resizing of the new window.

```
window.open("http://www.domainname.ext/yourfile","windowname","resizable=no");
```

Read more here

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

Comment: see , this option applicable for only IE. not for firefox, safari, opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can flag a popup as non-resizeable like this:

`window.open('http://example.com/', 'popUpWindow', 'width=400,height=150,`**`resizable=no`**`,scrollbars=yes');`

Comment: @Lalit Current versions of Firefox don't allow this for usability/accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

when opening the window, use resizable=no or resizable=0

```
window.open("sample.aspx", "samplename", "resizable=no");
```